# Folder/file permission issue using a MSI Installer created with VS2013

Tags: c#, file, permissions, installation, directory

I've created an installer, for an application I made, using Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension in VS2013.
All is more or less fine except that all the files and folders created by the setup are read-only and it is an issue when the application runs.
Is there a way to tell the installer to leave those folders writable?

I've searched online but I found only vague hints and some code in C++. If it's possible I would prefer something in C# (if code will be needed).

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to say where the files are. If they are in the ProgramFiles (or CommonFiles or similar location) then you cannot write to them, and the solution is to put them in an appropriate location like User's Application Data. The Program Files folder has always been restricted for limited users.

Comment: Sorry if I omitted a useful information, my fault. 
The files I need to modify are placed in a Program Files subfolder so I think you already give me the answer.
It will probably be better to change my application to read and write them from a more appropriate location!